# Change react-native-router-flux scene using a variable

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I am using react-native-router-flux for the navigation in my react-native mobile app.

I want to call `Actions.sceneKey()` from drawer using a variable `sceneKey` which will be based on the store state.
Let's say, there are 3 menus in drawer:

- menu1
- menu2
- menu3

I just want to call `Actions.{{ selectedMenu }}`, is this somehow possible?

Comment: Do you want to navigate to another menu? I am doing this by calling Actions.home()// in case home is my scene key. You can also pass parameters Actions.home({key:value}). You can use switch case or of condition to know current menu and call it using above syntext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *bracket notation*, see [property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).
Here is a example of how you can use it:

```
const selectedMenu = 'menu1'; //menus values coming from your store
Actions[selectedMenu]();
```

Make sure the variable is of type string and matches one of your defined routes.